# Eigen: vectorize solver?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

in my code, I repeatedly have to solve linear equation systems of the form:

```
A * xr = yr
A * xg = yg
A * xb = yb
```

So the matrix A is fix and I have three solution vectors yr, yg, yb (one for each color channel) and I'm searching the three vectors xr, yg and yb.

in code I do it like

```
Eigen::LDLT<MatrixXf> solver(num_coeffs);
solver.compute(A);
for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
  x[c].noalias() = solver.solve(y[c]);
}
```

I know that Eigen can use sse and avx instructions to speed up certain computations, but this seems to be an optimal case to vectorize over the input y and run the computation for all three components in parallel.
Is this possible with Eigen and if so, how?

Also, is it possible to create a matrix of which the "scalar" type is Array3f instead of float?

Comment: Just make `x` and `y` matrices with 3 columns.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. how will code be vectorized? does it make sense to make the matrices 4 columns wide (with all zeroes in the fourth column) to help vectorization?

Comment: That might help, if you make the matrices row-major. Whether that is worth it, depends on how you use `xrgb` afterwards, how many pixels you calculate, etc